# Problems with understanding splitAt in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

So I have found that the built-in splitAt function in Haskell can be defined as follows:

```
splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
-- Pre: n >= 0
splitAt n []
    = ([], [])
splitAt n (x : xs)
    = if n == 0
      then ([], x : xs)
      else (x : xs', xs'')
  where
    (xs', xs'') = splitAt (n - 1) xs
```

What I don't understand here/can't get my head around is the where part.

As an example,

`splitAt 2 "Haskell"` should return `(["Ha"],["skell"])`, but I don't really understand how it works here to define `(x:xs',xs'')` as another function? How would this look like visually?

With the example:

```
splitAt 2 "Haskell"
  = (('H':xs',xs''))
```

^ so this then does `splitAt 1 "askell"`, but I'm very confused as to what happens to the `xs',xs''` in the tuple above...

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "define (x:xs',xs'') as another function"?

Comment: @sepp2k I mean this  where
    (xs’, xs’’) = splitAt (n - 1) xs

Comment: That's not another function.  That's equivalent to `case splitAt (n-1) xs of (xs', xs'') -> if n == 0 then ...`  It's just running `splitAt (n-1) xs` and calling the first part of the result `xs'` and the second part `xs''`.

Comment: I can't really visualize what is happening to the string (x:xs). What is x actually apprehended onto in (x : xs', xs'')?

Comment: @AinJalut `x` is prepended to `xs'`.

Answer (score 6):

```
(xs', xs'') = splitAt (n - 1) xs
```

This takes the result of `splitAt (n - 1) xs`, which is a pair, and assigns the name `xs'` to the first element of that pair (i.e. the first `n - 1` elements of `xs`) and `xs''` to the second element (i.e. the remaining elements).

```
(x:xs', xs'')
```

This produces a pair. The first element of that pair is a list that's the result of prepending `x` to `xs'` (i.e. to the first `n-1` elements of `xs`). The second element is `xs''` (i.e. the remaining elements of `xs`).

Comment: @AinJalut `xs'` is never treated as `x` - `x` is an element and `xs'` is a list, so one could never be treated as the other. The only repetition here is in the fact that the function is recursive (so in that sense the code repeats for each recursive call).

Comment: sorry, I still have difficulty understanding. Let's take splitAt 3 "Programming" as an example. So when we arrive at splitAt n (x:xs), you are saying it will do something like (p:r, o)? What's next? And also, why would we put the third element into the space after the comma? This is splitting the wrong things, surely?

Comment: @AinJalut If we do `splitAt 3 "Programming"`, this matches the case `splitAt n (x : xs)` with `n = 3`, `x = 'P'` and `xs = "rogramming"`. So the line `(xs', xs'') = splitAt (n-1) xs` becomes `(xs', xs'') = splitAt 2 "rogramming"`. So `xs'` becomes `"ro"` and `xs''` becomes `"gramming"`. So the result, `(x:xs', xs'')`, will be `('P' : "ro", "gramming")`, which is `("Pro", "gramming")`.

Comment: sepp2k, where is the recursion here then? Does it not reach n=0 after splitAt 2 "rogramming"?

Comment: @AinJalut The recursion is in the fact that `xs'` and `xs''` depend on the result of `splitAt 2 "rogramming"`, which here I simply stated to be `("ro", "gramming")` because I didn't want to go through the whole thing for `splitAt 2 "rogramming"` again.

Comment: well I understand everything apart from the very last part anyway. Hence, when we get to splitAt 2 "rogramming" then this repeats (x:xs',xs'') again with r as x?

Comment: @AinJalut When we get to the recursion, the whole function gets executed again with `x = 'r'` and `xs = "ogramming"`, yes.

Comment: @AinJalut `splitAt 3 "Programming"` uses `splitAt 2 "rogramming"`, which uses `splitAt 1 "ogramming"`, which uses `splitAt 0 "gramming"`, which produces `("", "gramming")` as its result (because it goes into the `then` of the `if`). So in `splitAt 1 "ogramming"` `xs'` is `""` and `xs''` is "gramming", meaning that its result, `(x:xs', xs'')` is `('o':"", "gramming") = ("o", "gramming")`. So in `splitAt 2 "rogramming"` `xs'` is "o" and `xs''` is "gramming", meaning that its result, `(x:xs', xs'')` is `('r':"o", "gramming") = ("ro", "gramming")`...

Comment: ... So in splitAt 3 "Programming" xs' is "ro" and xs'' is "gramming", meaning that its result, `(x:xs', xs'')` is `('P':"ro", "gramming") = ("Pro", "gramming")`.